# Spring JSON databinding of nested objects doesn't work

Tags: java, json, spring, data-binding

I have the following `Person` class containing another `Car` class

```
public class Person {
    private String name
    private Car car;        
    ... getter and setters
}

public class Car {
    private String manufacturer;
    ... getter and setters
}
```

In Javascript I do the following:

```
person = new Object();
person.name = "Bob";

person.car = new Object();

car = person.car;

car.manufacturer = "Mercedes";

$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl.com',
    type: 'POST',
    data: person,
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
    complete: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

When using the autobinding function I get the following error:

Function:

```
public @ResponseBody Car validateCar( Car car, HttpServletRequest servletRequest){
        ...
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'car[manufacturer]' of bean class [com.example.Person]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'car[manufacturer]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was []
```

What do I have to do to make the mapping work?

btw: my POST data looks like this:

```
name: Bob
car[manufacturer]: Mercedes
```

stringified as JSON it looks the following (i tested it but I don't stringify it)

```
{"name":"Bob",
 "car": {
  "manufacturer":"Mercedes"
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the JSON format of your POST data?

Comment: I've added it below now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your passing in a Car hash and trying to autobind it to a Person object. For this to work, your hash would need to be look like person[car[manufacture]]]. Try passing in your person object in the javascript and then pulling the car object out of the autobinded person object.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. i just did this error in my example. i've updated it now. in my real code the problem is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing @RequestBody on your Car:

```
public @ResponseBody Car validateCar( @RequestBody Car car, HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
```

Comment: Before just had the person class without the car class nested. And it was working fine without @RequestBody. If I use it now i get 415: unsupported media type.

Comment: Okay, good, this is more because of the Accept header not being present. I am not sure how it was working before without the @RequestBody annotation! Can you confirm you have `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` annotation in your application context.

Comment: You also may have to stringify the data before posting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: i am sorry, i've tried both. 'mvc-annotation-driven' messes up the whole project and stringify causes '415 unsupported media' type errors. thanks for your help. i think i need to do a larger refactoring in my project.